# xdg-open is only using gedit

Tags: gnome, gedit, xdg-open

Something went wrong on a whole bunch of machines, and I can't figure out what or where or when or how.

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.10 (Santiago)

All of my desktop icons are not working.  Whenever I click on a desktop icon, the icon's underlying text file is opened in `gedit` .

I read a comment about `xdg-mime` but I don't know if the output is correct or not:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype ASIST.desktop 
text/plain; charset=us-ascii
$ xdg-mime query filetype /usr/share/pixmaps/keyring.png 
application/octet-stream
$ xdg-mime query filetype Desktop/gnome-terminal.desktop 
application/octet-stream
```

...but it doesn't seem to matter, because all three files are opened (or at least sent) to `gedit`.  (`gedit` won't open the png file)

What did I break, and how do I fix it?

Comment: the output of xdg-mime is indeed wrong. it should be `application/x-desktop` and `image/png`. Which distribution are you using?

Comment: @blaimi  Sorry -- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.10 (Santiago)

Answer (score 0):

Very sorry, it was essentially user error.

My security requirements include that the `root` user's `umask` is 0077.  I recently installed some files on all of these machines, and had to run `update-mime-database` , which rebuilt the entire `/usr/share/mime` directory -- and applied the `umask`, thus blocking all non-root users from accessing the directory.